# Retry in Camunda

Tags: java, camunda

I'm new to Camunda and I've been trying to get my head around the way it handles retries. Given the code below, is it possible to trigger a retry only when error_type_1 is caught?

```
} catch (error_type_1 e) {
        log.error(e);
} catch (error_type_2 e) {
        log.error(e);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a code from your java delegate? In that case, you need to throw exception to trigger an incident.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I can think of two options:

1) Rethrow a BpmnError, which will cause a business exception which you can handle in some error events. https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.3/org/camunda/bpm/engine/delegate/BpmnError.html

2) Implement custom IncidentHandler https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/incidents/#implement-custom-incident-handlers

Comment: Thank you. Assuming that I want to throw a BpmnError, is Camunda going to retry the task (if the retry is set as <camunda:failedJobRetryTimeCycle>R2/PT15S</camunda:failedJobRetryTimeCycle)?

Comment: If you will handle the exception in the diagram, it won't be retried. You can create an “intermediate catching error event” like this: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/examples/tutorials/error-handling/#bpmn-2-0-error-event

Answer (score 3):

you can add the retry and also retry after what time to your tasks initiator property 
[image]

[reference](https://bpmn.io/blog/posts/2016-properties-panel-050.html)